# Can we get a "learn more..." link to tag wikis on the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web

The tag wikis have never been very easy to find, but on the mobile site it is especially hard.

It would be useful to have a ***learn more...*** link to tag wikis on the mobile site, from the tag question lists, or from the tag list?  As far as I can tell, the tag wikis are not particularly discoverable on the mobile site.

[image: learn more link from question list]

Or something subtle, like a little icon beside the tags in the tag list? ( I realize that currently the main site does not even link to the tag wikis from the main tag list page, except for *edit...* links)

[image: tag list links]

Comment: This is because the tag wiki page doesn't actually exist on mobile (it's not optimized), and they don't link to non-mobile pages from the mobile site. So the only way they'd ever add a link is if they optimized the info page for mobile viewing.

Comment: @animuson I get that, but _not optimized_ != _not exist_ and certainly _not optimized_ != _not useful_.  Its a different discussion but IMO there's a  bigger UX problem in needing to scroll to the bottom and switch to the main site to get at additional content then & back to mobile, than to display a non-optimized page without losing the mobile cookie when returning to mobileoptimized content.

Comment: And another person could say that unexpectedly being switched to the full site is a bigger UX problem, and I agree with that person.

Comment: @animuson hence the IMO :)